# Arrow Keys - Prevent Default on Select Element

Tags: javascript, html

so I have a little bit of a very specific problem and I was hoping that there's a simple answer that I just haven't yet found.


Basically, I have a `select` element, and, while selecting an `option` in the select element I would like to be able to hold down the arrow up and down keys without changing the option, if that makes sense. Essentially, I need to get rid of the native key bindings for the select element so that, while pressing the up or down keys, it does not change the option I want to select. I have tried the following:

```js
select_element.onkeyup = evt => evt.preventDefault();
select_element.onkeydown = evt => evt.preventDefault();
```

But it does not seem to work. I suppose a last-ditch scenario would be to completely recreate the select element from scratch, but I would really like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: [This section of the select documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#customizing_select_styles) has the arrow keys disabled. Does this help your situation?

Comment: Hi cSharp,  thank you for the link! Yes, you're right, I've ended up opting for that route, though I'll still leave the question open because I'm interested as to whether there's a super simple way of doing this instead of having to rewrite the select element from scratch.